# How can I use load() to refresh a div without duplicating the element?

Tags: jquery

I use this code to refresh a div with the `id="my"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recp() {
  setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#my").load(location.href+ ' #my');
});
}
</script>


<div id="my"><?php echo date('a:i:s'); ?></div>
```

It works, but it generates this code:

```
<div id="my"><div id="my">pm:25:40</div></div>
```

How can refresh the div without generating a double div?

In other words how can refresh only this div:

```
<div id="my"><?php echo date('a:i:s'); ?></div>
```

Comment: @robert-harvey Same problem with others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add another div as a container and load content to it, like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recp() {
  setInterval(function() 
  {
    $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #my');
  });
}
</script>

<div id="result">
  <div id="my"><?php echo date('a:i:s'); ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alter your code to use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of `.load()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recp() {
  setInterval(function() {
      $.get(location.href, function(data){ 
          $('#my').empty().append( $(data).find('#my').children() );
      });
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: get() will not meet the need. load() allows him to target the #get div within the fetched page.

Comment: @John, i have already handled that in my code in the callback method.. (*the `find('#my')` part*)

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Although I would do: $('#my').html($(data).find('#my').html());

Comment: @John, that would do as well, but i prefer to not convert back and fort to text..

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recp() {
  setInterval(function() 
    {
        $("<div/>").load(location.href+ ' #my', function(response, status, xhr) {
            $("#my").replaceWith(response);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: keep in mind, that the callback in `load()` is called after the method has already inserted its contents in the DOM. In this case there will be a duplicate ID in the DOM when you try to `replaceWith` and that might yield undocumented results..

Comment: Since the '<div/>' is created on the fly, but not yet inserted into the DOM, I don't think there would be a duplicate ID. I don't think. Then it is removed so it for sure won't be there next time it is fired.

Comment: just spotted an error in the concept.. `response` holds the ***whole*** page fetched (*unfiltered by the used selector*)