# Jquery Reload is showing double posts when there isn't doubles in the database

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a site I am working on and it has a chat system that has been coded the issue we are having is that when the page is reloaded it's showing double posts but there aren't any double posts in the database.

```
 <script>
                (function($)
                {
                    $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $.ajaxSetup(
                        {
                            cache: false,
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                $('#content').show();
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                $('#content').show();
                            },
                            success: function() {
                                $('#content').show();
                            }
                        });
                        var $container = $("#show");
                        //$container.load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>chatview');
                        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
                        {
                            $container.load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>chatview');

                        }, 1000);
                    }); 

                     $('#submit').click(function(e) {

                        submitChat(e);

                     });

                    $('#message').keydown(function(e) { 

                         if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

                             submitChat(e);

                         }

                    });

                    function submitChat(e){
                        var post_data = {
                            'message': $("#message").val(),
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>chat_validation",
                            data: post_data
                        });

                         e.preventDefault();

                         $('#message').val('');
                    }

                })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Here are images of the page and the database.
[How it shows on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8moyE.png)
[The database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb3LF.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to check if [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021062/use-success-or-complete-in-ajax-call) can help you

Comment: Several questions: What is chatview? Is it a nested div inside the container that you use to populate the data into? Or you just directly load it into "#show"? What is the php block generating, and what is your final string inside the .load function. It should look something like : 'http://mysite.domain/data #innerElementId' (it's important that there is actually a space between the url and id). Refer to this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512671/4108884

Comment: chatview is just where the information is gathered from the database I can post a image of what is coded if it is needed.

Comment: Most likely not related but in your ajax setup you have some redundant code that might cause problems. .complete() runs whether the call was successful or not whilst .success() runs only if the call was successful.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but I got it fixed it was a div misspelling on my part