# How to refresh div repeatedly without duplicating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<div id="result" class="cart-content">
[_divmenu]
<div id="cartid" class="cart-one-goods">
    <img src="../templates/img/[_image]" alt="товар" class="cart-img-goods">
    <h3 class="cart-name-goods">[_name]</h3>
    <button class="cart-btn btn-plus" data-id=[_id] data-qu=[_quantity]></button>
    <input  class="cart-number-goods" value="[_quantity]" type="text">
    <button class="cart-btn btn-minus" data-id=[_id] data-qu=[_quantity]></button>
    <p class="cart-price-goods">[_summary] р.</p>
    <button class="cart-btn cart-delete" data-id=[_id]></button>
</div>
[_divmenu]
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".cart-one-goods").on('click', '.btn-plus', function(){
        id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        qu = $(this).attr("data-qu");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../moduls/plus-minus-cart.php',
            data: {
                idtovara: id, 
                quant: qu,
                plus: 'plus'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #cartid');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

After click button data in div 'result' update only one time.

How to change this code to update div every time clicking button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512671/8448942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Reference:- [Understanding Event Delegation jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Since `cart-one-goods` div is inside `result` container that's why after first refresh it's not working

Do like below:-

```
$(".cart-content").on('click', '.cart-one-goods .btn-plus', function(){
    id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    qu = $(this).attr("data-qu");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../moduls/plus-minus-cart.php',
        data: {
            idtovara: id, 
            quant: qu,
            plus: 'plus'
        },
        success: function(data) {
                $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #cartid');
        }
    });
});
```

Note:-

If `$(".cart-content").on('click', '.btn-plus', function(){` not worked then try `$(document).on('click', '.btn-plus', function(){`

Answer (score 1):

Well since you have mentioned a `childSelector` which is `.btn-plus` the function won't work the second time as after load fuction the element with `.btn-plus` class is not present in it. So you could either mention another `childSelector` which remains intact after load or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery ajax() Method and use `document.getElementById(divid)innerHTML = ""` 
in every call to clear div

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$(".cart-one-goods").on('click', '.btn-plus', function(){
 $.ajax(
    id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    qu = $(this).attr("data-qu");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../moduls/plus-minus-cart.php',
        data: {
            idtovara: id, 
            quant: qu,
            plus: 'plus'
        },
        success: function(data) {
                $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #cartid');
        }
    });
},5000)
});
```

it will refresh ur div in every 5 sec